# How to get superfish sub menus top-aligned?

Tags: jquery, superfish

On the [example here](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples) each submenu will be aligned with the item you positioned the mouse over. However, because my menu contains very many items, I would like each submenu to be top-aligned with the *column* (ie. the parent ul) of the item, not the item itself. This way, all submenus will always start at the same vertical position right below the main (horizontal) menu.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG that was easy. After spending hours trying out JS solutions, I just figured that at all I need to do is setting the li to position:static instead of relative. Except the first level, though, so the solution is:

#main_menu li.current li.current { position: static !important }