# Superfish js sub menu align top

Tags: jquery, css, superfish

I am trying to get the submenus on my superfish js menu to all align to the top instead of popping out of the parent li.  I have tried this solution:
[How to get superfish sub menus top-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619380/how-to-get-superfish-sub-menus-top-aligned)
and it did not work for me.
My menu is at: http://www.chipmandesignarch.com/index.php at the bottom, does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First i suggest you not to use IDs multiple times! An ID is always a **unique** identifier... change your `<ul id="top">`to `<ul class="top">`.

And your HTML contains a lot of `<font>`-Tags. [Really? Are you serious?](http://www.cssnewbie.com/replacing-font-tag-tips/) **This element was deprecated in HTML 4.01!**

To fix your issue remove `position: relative;` from `.sf-menu li` found in superfish.css line 8

```
/* change this…  */
.sf-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

/* …to this or even remove this style */
.sf-menu li {}
```

Comment: LOL, I totally agree on the markup, I am not in control of that, it is setup woth their outdated cms.  Trying your idea now.

Comment: OK, that worked on my vertical align issue, thank you.  Now I just have to figure out why the menu is not opening to the current page's menu item by default...